# jQuery Error regarding .text

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.taskStatus').text(function(n, oldcontent) {
     if (oldcontent == "Done") return "<a href='blah.com'>Click Here</a>";
  });
}); 


<span id="taskStatus_34" class="taskStatus">Done</span>
```

Why does the above code display the following on my webpage

Screenshot below:

[image]

Browser: Chrome 6.0.472.55
jQuery: 1.4.1

Edit: Apparently, it works for p (paragraph) tags, but not for divs and spans.

Edit: Using mcgrailm's answer, I ended up using the following code:

```
$('.taskStatus').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'Done') $(this).html("<a href='blah.com'>Click Here</a>"); 
});
```

Comment: Are you running jQuery < 1.4?  If so, passing a function as the argument to `$.text()` is not supported and it will be treated as a string.

Comment: @Sean Bright, I updated my project to use jquery-1.4.1 and it produced the same results.

Comment: one thing to note is that it works for "<p>" tags.

Comment: please see my edit in either case you need to swap the quotes around ohh and do that every where you add html so that your html quotes are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the text() expects a string

so you could do

```
   $('.taskStatus').each(function(){
    if($(this).text()== 'Done')  $(this).text("<a href='blah.com'>Click Here</a>");
   });
```

EDIT

you should change this line

```
 if (oldcontent == "Done") return "<a href='blah.com'>Click Here</a>";
```

to

```
if (oldcontent == "Done") return '<a href="blah.com">Click Here</a>'
```

Comment: I thought the code was self explanatory. If the old content is "Done" then I want to replace it with a link.

Comment: huh did see that when I looked there first

Comment: To mcgrailm's credit, I ended up using the .each function and setting the .html property.  Thanks.

Comment: interestingly I copied your original code and pasted into page on my server and it worked fine